# find extrema of a multivariable function Lagrange

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I need to evaluate the extrema of this function :

$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

restricted on: $R=\{x^2-y^2-z^2+16<=0\}$ \ $\{0,0,0\}$

boundary : $\theta R=\{x^2-y^2-z^2+16=0\}$ \ $\{0,0,0\}$

using the Lagrange multiplier method :
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{-2x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=2x\lambda\\
\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=-2y\lambda\\
\frac{-2z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=-2z\lambda\\
x^2-y^2-z^2+16=0
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

I found out --> $(0,0,\pm 4),(0,\pm 4,0),(\pm 4,0,0)$

Using the second derivate test I got :

$(0,0,\pm 4)$ -> Max

$(\pm 4,0,0),(0,\pm 4,0)$ -> Saddle points

eventually : $f(\pm 4,0,0)=f(0,\pm 4,0)=f(0,0,\pm 4)=\frac{1}{16}$

The image of this function is : $f(R)=[something,\frac{1}{16}]$

Can you help me figure out if I missed something? and if I got it right, is there a reason why there is no minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint $\ x^2 - y^2 - z^2 + 16 \le 0\ $ is not satisfied by $\ \left(\pm 4, 0, 0\right)\ $, so it's not even a feasible point, let alone an extremum.

All points of the form $\ \left(\,0, y, z\,\right)\ $ with $\ y^2 + z^2 = 16\ $ satisfy the Lagrange extremality conditions, and are all maxima, since $\ f\left(\,0,y,z\,\right)\ = \frac{1}{16}\ $ for such points, and the constraint $\ x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \le 16\ $ implies that its value cannot be any larger than that.

There are also arbitrarily large values of $\ x, y,\ \mbox{and } z\ $ that can satisfy the constraint $\ x^2 - y^2 - z^2 \le 16\ $. If $\ x=a^2 + 1, y=2a,\ $ and $ z=a^2 - 1\ $, for instance, then $\ x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 0 \le 16\ $ for any value of $\ a\ $,  and $\ a\ $ can be made aribitrarily large.  Thus, although the value of the objective function is always *strictly* positive, it can nevertheless be made arbitrarily close to zero, which is therefore its infimum, and $\ f\left(R\right) = \left(0, \frac{1}{16}\,\right]\ $.

Comment: Thank you!-----

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrange equations are not all consistent, as we obtain
$$ \frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ = \ 2x· \lambda \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -2x \ · \left[ \ \lambda \ + \ \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ \right] \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$
$$ \frac{-2y}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ = \ -2y· \lambda \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2y \ · \left[ \ \lambda \ - \ \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ \right] \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$
$$ \frac{-2z}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ = \ -2z· \lambda \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2z \ · \left[ \ \lambda \ - \ \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2} \ \right] \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

[The denominator in the derivatives given in the post is inaccurate, but does not materially affect the conclusion.]

The expression in brackets in the latter two equations doesn't tell us much.  We can extract that $ \ x \ , \  y \ , \ \text{or}  \ \ z = 0 \ \ , $ but we will see that this is not giving us a complete description of the solution.

We can arrive at a geometrical interpretation of the situation by treating the function  $ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \ $ as the "reciprocal distance-squared"  for a point $ \ (x,y,z) \ $ measured from the origin.  Expressed in "standard form" for a quadric surface, the region $ \ R \ $  is $ \ -x^2+y^2+z^2 \ \ge \ 16 \ $ with the boundary $ \ \partial R \ $ being $ \ -x^2+y^2+z^2 \ = \ 16 \ \ . $  We see then that this boundary is an "inner surface" which is a hyperboloid of one sheet with its symmetry axis being the $ \ x-$axis [depicted in the graph below].  The region $ \ R \ $ comprises all points "outside" of this surface, extending infinitely.

Writing the hyperboloid equation as $ \ y^2+z^2 \ = \ 16 + x^2 \ \ , $ we observe that the "narrowest" cross-section occurs at $ \ x = 0 \ \ , $ giving us a circle in the $ \ yz-$plane with a radius of $ \ 4 \ $ centered on the $ \ x-$ axis.  So the critical points $ \ ( 0 \ , \ \pm4 \ , \ 0) \ $ and $ \ ( 0 \ , \ 0 \ , \ \pm4) \ $ are "degenerate" and belong to the minimal-distance "ring" $ \ y^2+z^2 \ = \ 16   \ \ , $ as **lonza leggiera** also describes. [This also indicates that the specified exclusion of the origin from $ \ R \ $ and $ \ \partial R \ $ in the problem statement is unnecessary, as the given inequality already prevents it from being included.]

Since no point in $ \ R \ $ is closer to the origin than $ \ 4 \ $ units, the **global maximum** for $ \ f(x,y,z) \ $ is $ \ \frac{1}{16} \ \ . $  There is no upper limit to distances from the origin for points in the region, so our function is bounded below by zero, but *does not* possess a global minimum.

[image]